# how to add custom code in config_override.php using Module Loader in sugarcrm?

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I just want to add some additional configuration code in `config_override.php` in SugarCRM. Is it possible to write in `manifest.php` file and append it through module loader. When I am adding using copy array in `$installdefs` in manifest file then sugar is replacing my file with `config_override.php` file.

```
$installdefs = array(
              'copy' => array(  
                   0 => array(
                'from' => '<basepath>/moduleName/myconfg.php',
                'to' => 'config_override.php',
            ), ), );
```

I just want to append in config_override.php not replace whole file .
Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your install package in `/scripts/post_install.php`:

```
function post_install() {
    require_once('modules/Configurator/Configurator.php');
    $cfg = new Configurator();

    /** Your setting to save in config_override.php */
    $cfg->config['myaddon_setting'] = true;
    $cfg->handleOverride();  
}
```